# lenovo y540 laptop keyboard key can only be used with another key

Tags: laptop, keyboard, lenovo-laptop

a while ago my "e" key stopped working on my lenovo y540 keyboard
But i found out that when i click it with another key any key it works fine
i did some googling and tried the solutions but non worked here is what i tried:
1.stopping windows auto drivers and uninstalled the hid keyboard drivers then restarted
2.downgraded to an older version of my bios and restoring it to default
3.i opened my laptop and unplugged my battery then held the power button for 60 seconds

Answer (score 0):

> when i click it with another key any key it works

The keyboard has a physical hardware issue inside it and the keyboard needs to be replaced.

You can likely use a USB Keyboard until you can get the replacement keyboard.

You can try booting with a bootable USB key to see if the keyboard works that way. I have not seen drivers that would cause this issue.

Comment: but the key works 100% when i click any other key on the keyboard with it is that really a hardware issue ?

Comment: Yes, it is a hardware problem inside the keyboard circuit. There is no driver or software setup that would cause this defect.